# Find XML node with a specific child using GPath

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, gpath

I am looking for a GPath expression to find a node with a specific child.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td name="line">1</td>
      <td name="price">10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td name="line">2</td>
      <td name="price">95</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td name="line">3</td>
      <td name="price">43</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In the example XML above, I would like to retrive the entire `tr` element that contains a `td` element with attribute `price` and text `95`.

In XPath I would be writing something like this:

```
//tr[td[@name='price' and text()='95']]
```

The code I tried and that worked looked like this...

```
xmlDoc.tr.td.find { node -> node.text() == '1' }.parent()
```

...but that would be more of an XPath equivalent like his:

```
//tr/td[@name='price' and .='95']/parent::*
```

In this exact scenario it would do, but I am not a huge fan of the parent axe. Suppose there would be a lot more child node levels, how would I go about "nested" predicates? Return a node which has a child which has child...?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tr` as the root for the find, and use the depth first property `**` to search the whole subtree

```
xmlDoc.tr.find { tr -> tr.'**'.find { it.name() == 'td' && it.text() == '1' } }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.